# I only want to click on a div without clicking the link in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please I am trying to click on a div(mark) without clicking the link. I have set the link to jquery cdn but when i click it, i only want the div (outer) to show to display block without going to the link. My code is below. When i click the circle on the bottom-right. it will display a big mark on the center of the parent div. But then it is going to the link, which i dont want.

```js
$(".news-box").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  return false;
});
$(".news-box").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".circle").css("display", "block");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".circle").css("display", "none");
});
$(".circle").on("click", function() {
  $(".outer").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 94px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  left: 10px;
}

.news-box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.img-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.news-descript {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
  color: -webkit-link;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.circle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: rgba(13, 16, 18, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  display: none;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: rgba(13, 16, 18, 1.0);
}

.mark {
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 7px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
  top: 2px;
}

.black {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.big-mark {
  border-right: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
}

.outer {
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-box">
  <a href="https://code.jquery.com/"></a>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="mark"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="black">
      <div class="big-mark">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inside">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 position one">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gJaSjx/timi_small.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="news-descript">
          <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix : 
pass the `e` argument to your event listener so you can call `preventDefault` method on it.

Why don't you remove the link if you don't use it?

```js
$(".news-box").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(".news-box").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".circle").css("display", "block");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".circle").css("display", "none");
});
$(".circle").on("click", function() {
 $(".outer").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
  img {
   width: 100px;
   height: 94px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
   top: 7px;
      left: 10px;
  }
  .news-box {
   width: 350px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 3px solid red;
   position: relative;

  }
  .img-box {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
  }
  .news-descript {
   margin-top: 15px;
   
  }
  a {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index: 1;
   bottom: 0;
   right:0;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  
  a:-webkit-any-link {
      color: -webkit-link;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .circle {
   width: 22px;
   height: 22px;
   background-color: rgba(13, 16, 18, 0.5);
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   transition: background-color 1s linear; 
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   z-index: 4;
   display: none;
  }
  .circle:hover {
   background-color: rgba(13, 16, 18, 1.0);
  }
  .mark {
   border-right: 3px solid white;
   border-bottom: 3px solid white;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   background-color: transparent;
   width: 7px;
   height: 15px;
   position: relative;
   left: 6px;
   top: 2px;
  }
  .black {
   width: 350px;
   height: 100px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .big-mark {
   border-right: 5px solid white;
   border-bottom: 5px solid white;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   width: 30px;
   height: 90px;
   margin: auto;
   
  }
  .outer {
   top: -3px;
   right: -3px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-box">
  <a href="https://code.jquery.com/"></a>
  <div class="circle">
   <div class="mark"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
   <div class="black">
    <div class="big-mark">
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inside"> 
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 position one">
     <div class="img-box">
      <img  src="https://preview.ibb.co/gJaSjx/timi_small.jpg" >
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
     <div class="news-descript">
      <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Absolutely that what makes the question ununderstandable. If you wont use a link why it is there? I read dozen times to understand but im notsure if i did. You want to go to the link on clicking news-box and on clicking circle you want to display check mark? or you want to display check mark where ever clicked is not important?

Comment: http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=3fc1d56f7780cbf6a5d2e16c55201c7a is an example of click the circle to check or click anywhere and go to the link.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use `<a>` only for refereance at all.

JS

```
$(".news-box").click(function() {
      window.location = $(this).attr("data-href"); 
      return false;    
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="news-box" data-href="https://code.jquery.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this  on your code. its is going because on page refreshed it will triggers the link . I remove the link and every works fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-box">
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="mark"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="black">
                <div class="big-mark">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inside"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 position one">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <img  src="https://preview.ibb.co/gJaSjx/timi_small.jpg" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="news-descript">
                        <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so please what should i put instead of this

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieved